# htaccess redirect to www. not working behind load balancer in one scenario

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Amazon Beanstalk so my infrastructure is

```
USER --(HTTPS)--> BEANSTALK BALANCER --(HTTP)--> EC2 INSTANCES
```

Now whether the users goes to

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
https://mydomain.com
http://mydomain.com
```

I want to always redirect to

```
https://www.mydomain.com
```

I got the https working but for some reason the `www` redirect is not working when I access the page directly `https://mydomain.com`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# If not on www., redirect to www. on SSL (does not work when accessing https://mydomain.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/status$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If not on SSL(ish), redirect to SSL (works)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/status$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `RewriteCond` are by default logical `AND` operations. Your two conditions check that the forwarded protocol is not https `AND` the requested host doesn't begin with `www`. Your input url `https://example.com` (has HTTPS but no www) does not meet both those conditions so the rules doesn't execute.

Since what the first redirect does is apply the `www` where not already present, you don't need to check `https` on that pass. Just check for the presence of the `www` and redirect to the preferred host, with `https://`.

```
# Do the SSL redirect first to protect your users
# If not on SSL(ish), redirect to SSL (works)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/status$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# If you don't mind a hard-coded domain here, you can avoid a second
# redirect if the www is missing...
# RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Then add the www.
# Do not check the protocol here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/status$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above results in possibly two redirects for the end user. It may be possible to bundle both of these into a single block, using an optional `()` group on the `www.` and capturing the rest of the host into `%1` for use in the `RewriteRule`.

This is untested...

```
# First condition is [AND] and just serves to grab the requested host
# optional, non-capture group for www. if present
# and a capture group into %1 for everything after www. no matter what
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
# Next 2 conditions are OR'd together
# Check for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
# Or the host doesn't start with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
# Rewrite as HTTPS, using the part of the domain following www.
# whether or not there was a www. originally...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```